# Windows - How can I prevent a JFrame from being hidden in desktop peek

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java-native-interface, jna

Since I use Rainmeter I noticed that it does not get hidden when using desktop peek. I was wondering if I could achieve something similar in Java using maybe JNA or JNI (Other libraries work fine too until it works).

I spent quite a few hours researching but could not find the answer to this question anywhere, and in general do not know where to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is desktop peek?  Do you mean "show desktop"?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yea but when u just hover over it.